# eclipse for android c source code - how to resolve compiler head file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, android-source, pandaboard

I am now using eclipse to develop driver and daemon on android platform in C code with a pandaboard, and I want to use eclipse plus CDT as an edit and browse tool.

I have imported android-source code into eclipse as a makefile project, and processing with indexer.

My problem is, since there are lots of head files for different archetecture(x86, arm, etc) like     etc, etc. Eclipse reports an error like "unresolved inclusion xxx" because there are too much candidates of those files. Can eclipse analysis makefile and select the correct path like compiler if I specify a variable or identifier to notify eclipse just like a makefile option?

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks,

-Yunfei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your driver work checkout:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source

In general when working with a Makefile project you need to give Eclipse a hand so it knows where to find the includes and which preprocessor symbols are defined.

Right click on your project. Select properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and symbols.
Add the most important include paths and the indexer results will become much better.